# Read a txt file and check the time?

Tags: javascript, node.js

so currently I have a text file which is getting data for each song that is played for example like from pandora it will grab the name and the song id and time it was played in a file so like this

```
'10:26:03 | [Songs] Current Song is ZzbEsMCR7lY. User is (Magic)'
```

How would I make it so each 3 hours it will read the text file and check if the song was played in the last three hours by checking the time and also the id, so basically it is checking the txt file's for the song and id and compare it to the song thats playing like I did above giving you the example of the pandora(But I am not doing this for pandora)... I am making this for a service called dubtrack which people can queue up songs and I am currently grabbing the song id's and time it was played and when someone types in chat like for example 'history' it will check the txt file and return that it played in the past 3 hours or it hasnt played in the past 3 hours...

Here is some code:

```
fs.readFile('chatlogs.txt', 'utf8', function () {};
```

Thank You Sorry for the long text I hope you understand what I am getting at here ...

Answer (score 1):

For doing something for example every 3 hours you can use cronjob. https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron. Hard to help with the comparing part since you have not given any code to work on.

Comment: well how would I get the code to check the time ? and respond if its been three hours

Comment: Open the link i wrote and read the documentation. Its on the landing page

Comment: it doesnt show how to read the file and get the time and id??!?!??!

Comment: I told you you didn't give a single line of code and no one will code it for you from scratch. I gave the link saying it solves your issues with doing something every x hours, not solving how to check what ever you want to check